# Why would the Changeling Queen not kill?

Tags: pinkamena

To my understanding (once the Drone is dead), the Cangeling Queen would kill every night, just like a drone. And couldn't be jailed or partied either.

However, I just got a night with no changeling kill, after the Drone has been long dead. How could this happen?

My deaths before the night were *Drone, Forger*, Mule, Town Drunk, Spellcaster and Watchpony.
My orders were to Bodyguard a random pony, Gumshoe to investigate the Consort (found that out later) and Veteran to stand guard.

The Consort got killed by Pinkamena and the Bodyguard got role blocked. Veteran had no intruders.

What role could have prevented the Queen from acting? What could prevent the Queen from acting in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Queen will only begin to kill once the Drone is dead, sometimes even starting the same night the Drone dies. However, killing is dangerous for her as it forces her to take actions that might reveal her identity. The game has a hidden 'queen desperation' flag which tracks how desperate she is to consume more love. She's pretty voracious so the chance she will hold off killing on a particular night is only 20%, but it can happen.

Pinkamena also has a hidden flag which will prevent her from attempting to kill on a given night, although for her it's only 10%. She might want to stay home and stitch some cutie marks together, or some other small accident prevented her from attacking that night.

These low-chance random 'off' nights were put in the game to give the player a puzzle sometimes, and maybe throw a spanner into their theory on the baddie's identities.

Source: I wrote it. :3

Comment: I have to say, I did think about contacting the creator for an answer a few times. Never tought you'd find the question here :)